# Disable password prompt upon startup in Ubuntu Server

Tags: 12.04, server

Currently, each time I restart my Ubuntu Server, it's prompting for a login password. How do I disable this feature so that I when I restart my Ubuntu server, it doesn't require me to enter credentials?

Version: Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

Comment: I'm curious. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: say for instance, while I am in development stage and want to save time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is not a secure procedure and you are not going to obtain anything with it (the processes are started before login), but well, these are the steps:

> To enable automatic login in Ubuntu server we need to edit the tty1
>   configuration file. To open this file up in nano use the following
>   command:
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/init/tty1.conf
> ```
>
> The very last line in this file should start with an exec command.
>   Delete this line and replace it with the following:
>
> ```
> exec /bin/login -f USERNAME < /dev/tty1 > /dev/tty1 2>&1
> ```
>
> Note that you need to change USERNAME to the username of the user that
>   you want to be automatically logged in. Once you reboot your system
>   you should be automatically logged in.

Source: http://nixgeeks.com/how-to-enable-automatic-login-in-ubuntu-server/

Comment: Thanks for the response. But isn't it a stand procedure? Don't a lot of hosting servers out there allow you to restart instances without having to log in again?

Comment: If the program you are running on your server starts up automatically (e.g. via crontab), you don't need to log in when your computer starts up. I never log into my ubuntu server computer when I boot up, and whenever I need to administer I use ssh.

Comment: Are processes really started before login? Does this require somekind of configuration? My user-specific cronjobs don't run unless I login.

Comment: Hm nm, I think that has to do with the home folder encryption in ubuntu.

Comment: Doesn't work for ubu desktop 12.04 lts. link's dead

Comment: For ubuntu desktop 12.04 LTS, click ubuntu > system tools > users and groups > account name > edit > uncheck login at startup, reset.